# Spring context:component-scan casting exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I have a strange error which I searched about alot on the internet. I could not figure it why I am getting this error. I found some explanations about that error on spring jira. I have `context:component-scan` in `applicationContext.xml` and I defines 5 packages in `com.sow.webservices` package. However when I add the controller package including controller classes, I throws

```
Error occured processing XML '[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String'. See Error Log for more details
```

This is component-scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sow.webservices.aop, 
                                          com.sow.webservices.exceptions,
                                          com.sow.webservices.models, 
                                          com.sow.webservices.services,
                                          com.sow.webservices.controller">
```

I would like to show you whole exception trace. Appreciate for your help.

```
!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core 1 0 2014-04-11 18:07:39.996
!MESSAGE Error occured processing '/SOW_WS/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:494)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:402)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:445)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Even if xml throws this exception I can run my application, but when I remove `com.sow.webservices.controller` it stops showing there is mistake sign but it gives 404 error. Since I am in trouble with component-scan, LocaleChangeInterceptor is not working and I can not internationalize my application

Comment: Just a thought, if these are the 5 packages you have and no filters, why don't you keep base package as "com.sow.webservices" instead of mentioning it all?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? You mentioned Spring JIRA and, yes, there is, indeed, an issue reported and fixed (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11221). Have you tried with the Spring versions that fixed that JIRA issue?

Comment: @Prasad, it is still in development, I may have anohter package containing sometrhing under 'com.sow' instead of 'com.sow.webservices'.
AndreiStefan , yes before I was using 4.0.2, But after reading that issue I moved on 4.0.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check your controllers, if one of them uses the annotation @ControllerAdvice try commenting it out and the weird thing is the error goes away. FREAKY!!!!

Comment: wouw. you are right. it worked. However this time my app exception can not be catched by a controller which use @ ControllerAdvice and its methods use the @ ExceptionHandler annotation.

Comment: nice.  this fixed my error which was just slightly different: java.lang.String; incompatible with java.lang.String

Comment: Ok but we need @ControllerAdvice, do you know how to replace it with an equivalent Spring XML configuration ?